# Is there any way that i can make few tables write proof in doctrine2 mysql

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I am building a Symfony 2.1 Doctrine 2.3 app. As I was not able to fully code the complex form, there is possibility that my few tables gets updated which I don't want.

Is there any way that I can lock those tables so that whatever happens data doesn't get updated there? Only records can be read only but no write in there.

Also doctrine should not show any error while doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using annotations:

```
@Entity(readOnly=true)
```

See [the documentation for details](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#entity).